# Keeping existing capital letters in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am using the following code to change the first letter of each word to a capital except for some trivial ones (a, of etc.)

```
f = open('/Users/student/Desktop/Harry.txt').readlines()[2]
new_string = f.title()
print (new_string)
```

What i would also like to do is have those exception words not capitalised as stated above but also have that any word that already has capitals letters (For e.g. CHINA, NSW) that those letters will be retained.

Comment: Even though your question is clear enough, the code you are showing is not helpful. The first line is not related to the question at all. What would be nice is an example string, the desired `new_string`, and the current `new_string`.

Comment: so you want to check if your string is already all uppercase...?

Comment: What about words like `'aBCDe'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

Using `str.capitalize`:

Why?

```
>>> "CAN'T".title()
"Can'T"

>>> "CAN'T".capitalize()
"Can't"
```

**Code:**

```
>>> strs = """What i would also like to do is have those exception words not capitalised as 
stated above but also have that any word that already has capitals letters
( For e.g. CHINA, NSW etc. ) that those letters will be retained."""
>>> words = {'a','of','etc.','e.g.'}  #set of words that shouldn't be changed
>>> lis = []
for word in strs.split():
    if word not in words and not word.isupper(): 
        lis.append(word.capitalize())
    else:    
        lis.append(word)
...         
>>> print " ".join(lis)
What I Would Also Like To Do Is Have Those Exception Words Not Capitalised As Stated Above But Also Have That Any Word That Already Has Capitals Letters ( For e.g. CHINA, NSW etc. ) That Those Letters Will Be Retained.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first requirement you can create a list containing the exception words:

```
e_list = ['a', 'of', 'the'] # for example
```

Then you can run something like this, using `isupper()` to check if the string is already all capitalized:

```
new = lambda x: ' '.join([a.title() if (not a in e_list and not a.isupper()) else a for a in x.split()])
```

Testing:

```
f = 'Testing if one of this will work EVERYWHERE, also in CHINA, in the run.'

print new(f)
#Testing If One of This Will Work EVERYWHERE, Also In CHINA, In the Run.
```

Comment: This will remove words that don't need to be capitalized, instead of keeping them as is.

Comment: @interjay Thank you for the feedback, it was missing an else statement in the list comprehension...